# Get indexed value from object over reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, indexing

I have the problem, that i don't know how to call the `this` property of an object instance over reflection.

I have the following method:

```
public object GetValue(SOP sop, object value)
{
    // 1. find the this getter/setter method for the value parameter
    // 2. Invoke the method and pass the result of GetIndexArray(sop) as a parameter
    // 3. return the result of the method
}
```

which should call the `this` property of the `value`-instance and return the value the property returns. 
The problem is, that i don't know the type of the `value`-instance, which is passed as a parameter.

The index which should be passed to the `this` property is given over the following method:

```
private object[] GetIndexArray(SOP sop)
```

But i don't know how to call the `this`-property. The `object`-instance can be anything, a `string`, `Dictionary`, ...

Does any one has an idea, how to solve the problem?

**EDIT:**
The `GetValue` method should do the follwing task, but dynamically over reflection:

```
public object GetValue(SOP sop, object value)
{
    // Non relfection, lets say 'value' is a Dicitionary<string, string> 
    // return value["key"];
    // The type of 'value' is unknown, and the index-parameter (the keys) are accessable over GetIndexArray()
}
```

**EDIT2:**
In c# every getter and setter can be invoked via reflection as a method. Is there a way, to get the methods for the "this" property? If it's possible, the problem can be solved with invoking the mesthods.

**Call of the GetValue method**

```
object pInst = parentInstance.GetType().GetProperty(VariableName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(parentInstance, null);

            var indexChldren = FindChildrenOfType<IndexNode>();

            if (indexChldren.Count > 0)
            {
                pInst = indexChldren[0].GetValue(sop, pInst);
            }
```

Comment: I am not clear what question is. Can you give an example?

Comment: @TuTran i have added an example. Thank you!

Comment: That does not make any sense to me. You can certainly call an indexer via reflection, but I still don't know what you want to *do*. How do you get the key when all you get is an object array? Is *that* the key?

Comment: Yes, the object array is the key. I get the key, lets say, over some configuration.

Comment: I also find it hard to understand, since your GetIndexArray already returns an array of objects, which should then be used as the key? What is SOP? in your example your return value is the value inside the Dictionary, not the index? You cannot use method overloading to fascilitate the possible GetValue methods? or check which type value is (i guess you could guess what kind objects would come back :))

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, i don't want to return the index, i want the "value behind the index". The index is no problem, access the value behind the index is the problem. SOP is the instance, which contians all configurations. What do you mean with: *You cannot use method overloading to fascilitate the possible GetValue methods?*? Maybe a solution would be, to access the index getter / setter as a method? Thank you!

Comment: i would like to see a specific call to your GetValue method, not simple the signatures of the methods with some cryptic questions...

Comment: @Icepickle i read-write my question and added the call of the GetValue method: `indexChldren[0].GetValue(sop, pInst);`. Thank you  for your help, it is hard for me to describe the problem as good as possible :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to remake the post, since my previous one didn't correctly do what it was supposed to do.

To check which indexers are on an object, you can use the following, which will

- Return null when object is null
- Return an empty IList when no indexers are found
- Return a list of MethodInfos with the found indexers

The trick to check it, is to check if a property has any `GetIndexParameters();`

```
public IList<MethodInfo> GetIndexProperties(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var type = obj.GetType();
    IList<MethodInfo> results = new List<MethodInfo>();

    try
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default | 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (props != null)
        {
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                var indexParameters = prop.GetIndexParameters();
                if (indexParameters == null || indexParameters.Length == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                var getMethod = prop.GetGetMethod();
                if (getMethod == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                results.Add(getMethod);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return results;
}
```

This works with a List, Dictionary, string, object with indexers, indexers defined with IndexerNameAttribute

As an example, i used this MainMethod, to try several possibilities

```
object[] exampleHayStack = new object[] {
    "This is a test of an indexer", 
    new TestIndexer(),
    null,
    string.Empty,
    new ClassIndexer(),
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "key", "value" } },
    new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" } };

ClassIndexer myIndexer = new ClassIndexer();

foreach (var obj in exampleHayStack)
{
    var methods = myIndexer.GetIndexProperties(obj);
    if (methods == null || methods.Count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} doesn't have any indexers", obj);
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Testing {0}", obj);
    foreach (MethodInfo mi in methods)
    {
        IList<object> indexParams = new List<object>();
        var requiredParams = mi.GetParameters();
        foreach (var par in requiredParams)
        {
            indexParams.Add(myIndexer.ParamForObject(obj, par));
        }
        try
        {
            var result = mi.Invoke(obj, indexParams.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("Result of requesting ({0}) = {1}", string.Join(",", indexParams), result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Which then results into:

```
Testing This is a test of an indexer
Result of requesting (21) = i
Testing TestReflection.Program+TestIndexer
Result of requesting (53) = 5
Result of requesting (Key) = Key item
 doesn't have any indexers
Testing
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
TestReflection.Program+ClassIndexer doesn't have any indexers
Testing System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
Result of requesting (key) = value
Testing System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
Result of requesting (5) = F
```

The complete implementation of the ClassIndexer you can find here, it contains an extra method for getting possible key values (but those you have already)

```
public class ClassIndexer
{
    Random pNext = new Random();

    public IList<MethodInfo> GetIndexProperties(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var type = obj.GetType();
        IList<MethodInfo> results = new List<MethodInfo>();

        try
        {
            var props = type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            if (props != null)
            {
                foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    var indexParameters = prop.GetIndexParameters();
                    if (indexParameters == null || indexParameters.Length == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var getMethod = prop.GetGetMethod();
                    if (getMethod == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    results.Add(getMethod);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return results;
    }

    public object ParamForObject(object obj, ParameterInfo pi)
    {
        if (obj is IDictionary)
        {
            int maxNumber = ((IDictionary)obj).Keys.Count;
            if (pi.ParameterType.Equals(typeof(int)))
            {
                return pNext.Next(maxNumber);
            }
            if (pi.ParameterType.Equals(typeof(string)))
            {
                int target = pNext.Next(maxNumber);
                foreach (var key in ((IDictionary)obj).Keys)
                {
                    target--;
                    if (target <= 0)
                    {
                        return key;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
        if (obj is string)
        {
            if (pi.ParameterType.Equals(typeof(int)))
            {
                return pNext.Next((obj as string).Length);
            }
        }
        if (obj is IList)
        {
            return pNext.Next(((IList)obj).Count);
        }
        if (pi.ParameterType.Equals(typeof(string)))
        {
            return "Key";
        }
        if (pi.ParameterType.Equals(typeof(int)))
        {
            return pNext.Next(100);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ClassIndexer()
    {
    }
}
```

For the rest, this was a good research, thanks for the question !

Comment: Thanks, but how do you know that the `PropertyName` must be `Item`? If i replace `WithIndexer` with a `string`, your code does not work. But thank you again!

Comment: (In case of a `string` it must be **Chars**)

Comment: Ok, but when i look at the definition of `string`, i found this: `public char this[int index] { get; }`. Thank you, maybe i have to do some `is` comparisons.

Comment: I updated my answer with a hopefully satisfying answer for you ;)

Comment: Thank you, `GetIndexParameters` did it! :)